# :last-child is not working in nested divs

Tags: html, css

I have simple `div` structure, In that I have 7 columns with `float: left`. I want to apply `float: right` to the last column by using `:last-child`, But it is not working.

Below is the HTML and CSS.

```
<div class="boc-practice-impact-main">
    <div class="bocpi-header">Practice Impact</div>
        <div class="bocpi-body-main">
            <div class="bocpi-column">1</div>
            <div class="bocpi-column">2</div>
            <div class="bocpi-column">3</div>
            <div class="bocpi-column">4</div>
            <div class="bocpi-column">5</div>
            <div class="bocpi-column">6</div>
            <div class="bocpi-column">7</div>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
        </div>
</div>

.boc-practice-impact-main {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: red;
}
.boc-practice-impact-main .bocpi-header {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #49bad7;
    line-height: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 3px;
}
.boc-practice-impact-main .bocpi-body-main {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #333333;
    line-height: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 3px;
}
.boc-practice-impact-main .bocpi-body-main .bocpi-column {
    width: calc(100%/7 - 21px);
    background-color: #f4f8fc;
    float: left;
    margin: 5px 21px 20px 0px;
    padding: 5px;
    min-height: 200px;
}
.business-outcome-main-div-new .bocpi-body-main .bocpi-column:last-child {
    width: calc(100%/7 - 20px);
    background-color: #ff0000;
    float: right;
    margin: 5px 0px 20px 0px;
    padding: 5px;
    min-height: 200px;
}
```

Advance thanks for the solution.

Comment: Try `bocpi-body-main:last-child .bocpi-column` Assuming that you *missed* the closing tags

Comment: your columns do not seem to be terminated correctly

Comment: Hi Akshay, it did not work for me.

Comment: Hi happymacarts, i am sorry. i corrected my html now. please check and give me solution if possible. thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no `last-child` *class* selector, it will target the last child of the `.bocpi-body-main`.

In your case you can get around it by deleting the `<div class="clearfix"></div>` and use a CSS based clear fix, using the pseudo element `::after`

```
.boc-practice-impact-main .bocpi-body-main::after {  /*  clearfix  */
  content: '';
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}
```

Stack snippets

```css
.boc-practice-impact-main {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: red;
}

.boc-practice-impact-main .bocpi-header {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #49bad7;
  line-height: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 3px;
}

.boc-practice-impact-main .bocpi-body-main {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #333333;
  line-height: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 3px;
}

.boc-practice-impact-main .bocpi-body-main::after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}

.boc-practice-impact-main .bocpi-body-main .bocpi-column {
  width: calc(100%/7 - 21px);
  background-color: #f4f8fc;
  float: left;
  margin: 5px 21px 20px 0px;
  padding: 5px;
  min-height: 200px;
}

.boc-practice-impact-main .bocpi-body-main .bocpi-column:last-child {
  width: calc(100%/7 - 20px);
  background-color: #ff0000;
  float: right;
  margin: 5px 0px 20px 0px;
  padding: 5px;
  min-height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="boc-practice-impact-main">
  <div class="bocpi-header">Practice Impact</div>
  <div class="bocpi-body-main">
    <div class="bocpi-column">1</div>
    <div class="bocpi-column">2</div>
    <div class="bocpi-column">3</div>
    <div class="bocpi-column">4</div>
    <div class="bocpi-column">5</div>
    <div class="bocpi-column">6</div>
    <div class="bocpi-column">7</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much LGSon. It worked for me. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

No `bocpi-column` element is the last child of its container.

`<div class="clearfix"></div>` or `<div class="bocpi-body-main">` are.

---

Your HTML is invalid. If you had used [a validator](https://validator.w3.org/nu/) it would have alerted you the many missing `</div>` tags in your code.